# Can WPF trace "Information" messages be ignored?

Tags: c#, wpf

For debugging purposes, I have brought the message level of WPF trace from "Warning" to "Verbose" ([here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409960.aspx)'s how I did it).

That caused hundreds of "Information" level messages to appear in the output window whenever I load my custom control.

I understand that these messages are usually harmless: most of time they say that I didn't specify a fallback value for a binding and that the default value of whatever type will be used.

I am however a bit concerned by the large amount of them. I wonder if this has any effect on performance. I have also noticed that it could be rather time consuming to fix all of them.

So my question is: is it worth my time to remove the cause of such messages or can I happily ignore them?

Comment: These message aren't warnings or errors. So you can of course ignore them.